# Styles and text not loading on safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari

I am having a weird issue and not been able to figure out what's causing this. 
This is my web page for example https://modern-woodmen-sandbox.everfi-next-sandbox.net/student/dashboard/mwasandbox/3-5-grade-band/152?locale=en

It works fine on every browser other than Safari on Mac. The issue is, when I land on this page, it shows a blank screen. And if I click anywhere on the page, it renders some stuff but not all. 
Like it shows this
[image]

And if I refresh the page, it loads the content fine and the way I expect.

Really appreciate your thoughts in this.

Thanks

It works fine on Chrome tho.

Comment: Unable to reproduce here on Safari/MacOS.

Comment: Try clearing your cache

Comment: already did that. no luck

Comment: I have no Mac to try this out, but the first step to debug anything like this is to open your browser's developer tools. Inspect the elements' style, and this will most certainly tell you what's wrong. If you still can't find out, update your question with what you see (what font is actually applied to the text, what color it is, are there any errors in the console, etc.). Oh, and since this does not seem to apply to all Safaris on Macs (comment above), please specify your OS version and browser version

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your '**Source Sans Pro**' fonts are loading properly.

Comment: Hi. If this comment/answer or any other one solved your issue, please upvote/mark it as accepted :)